# I have a question about changing the order of the integrals

Tags: measure-theory

Let $N_1=\chi_{[0,1]}$ and $N_n=N_1*N_1*\cdots*N_1$ ($n$ times convolution)

and let

$f:R\longrightarrow C$ be a continuous function.

Why is
$$\int_R \int_0^1 N_n(x-t)f(x) \, dt \, dx=\int_0^1 \int_R N_n(x-t)f(x) \, dx \, dt?$$

Why can we use Foubini's theorem?

Comment: Because $N_n(x)$ has bounded support.

Comment: Why shouldn't we be able to use Fubini's theorem?